# How to pin a tab opened with quick open by keyboard shortcut instead of double clicking the tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use `ctrl+p` then find a file I need to edit and it opens in a tab. Now if I go to another file by using `ctrl+p` the first tab is replaced by the newer file's tab. To avoid that I have to use mouse by double clicking the tab to pin it.

I use Vim extension and mostly like using keyboard, very annoying for me to reach mouse to pin a tab. Is there a keyboard shortcut to pin a tab?

I tried searching available keybindings for `pin`, `window` and `tab`, I didn't find any that indicates this is possible, maybe named something else or doesn't exist.

If there is no native keybinding, is there any extension that can allow me to do that?

Comment: A right arrow will open the file as you like.  I don't know if that will conflict with vim keybindings?

Comment: Great! You should add this as an answer!

Comment: it doesn't conflict with vim keybindings and works perfectly

Comment: Yes, you just have to hit `esc` to close the quickopen panel, but if you want to open more than one file that is nice.

Comment: There are a number of questions discussing this preview option - it can be disabled by the way.  Search the settings for "enable preview".

Answer (score 4):

You can pin the current tab with the following key chord:

**Mac**: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
**Win**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Tab Context Menu Pin]

You can also bind to another shortcut if you'd prefer something else

[image: Pin Keyboard Shortcuts]

Answer (score 1):

On Mac I press first Cmd+K, then hit Enter. This makes the temporarily previewed tab normally opened. (Font style on its tab title changes from italic to regular.)

On other operating systems you may figure out the equivalent control key. (My guess is maybe Ctrl, but haven't tested.)

Comment: CTRL + K, ENTER works perfectly.